# Using ColumnName instead of ColumnLabel with clojure.java.jdbc

Tags: jdbc, clojure, sas

I am currently using clojure.java.jdbc to connect to a SAS server and pull data from it. I can connect and run queries. The one problem that I have run into is that the clojure jdbc library uses the column labels when constructing the keys in the results map. In many instances this field is coming back blank and I would prefer to use the column name instead.

One work around would be to specify the label as part of the query, which I can do if there are no other simpler options.